# Unable to install Java Runtime Environment (ver 7 update 65)

Tags: installation, java, eclipse, installer, jre

**Background:** I am trying to setup `PyDev` on `Eclipse Luna`. I have managed to download and installed `Eclipse Luna`. But on start up, it said I need to download and install latest `Java Runtime Environment`.

**Note:** Currently I have `Java 6 Update 13`. But `Eclipse Luna` needs `Java 7`.

So, I have downloaded the latest `Java 7 Update 65` installer (offline - 32bits) from this [Link from Oracle](http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp). But upon clicking the "install" button on the first page of the installer, the installer windows just disapper without any error message or anything.

I have tried changing the destination folder, but it still give me the same result. I have also tried installing using the online installer without success.

I also attempted to uninstall the previous version of java, but in "Add or Remove Programs" windows, there is no "Remove" button beside the `Java 6 Update 13`. So, I was not able to unable to uninstall the previous  Java version.

Now, I am stuck without being able to install the latest version of Java. What is causing the problem?

**FYI:** I am using windows xp SP3 32bits and google chrome as default browser.

Comment: I can't answer what is wrong but I can suggest going to Oracle and downloading the tar.gz and install it manually. You can use 7Zip to unpack the files and then edit the eclipse.ini and point the Java version at that directory. Hope that helps.

Comment: @JasonMcD I can't find the option to download in tar.gz at Oracle page like you said. Any idea?

Comment: Might as well get 8! http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html. You can download the .exe and unpack it with 7zip. Sorry I thought there was a tar.gz but that's just for the JRE and not the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

The java you have downloaded [this link](http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp) is not a JDK try Installing the JDK.

For uninstalling the previous version use the java uninstalling tool
[see this for tool](http://java.com/en/download/uninstallapplet.jsp)
 after uninstalling the previous version install the new one.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but what i need is JRM(Java Runtime environment) just to run `Eclipse`. I am not going to develop java program so i don't think i need `JDK`.

Comment: yes but since JDK will also install JRE for you try installing jdk.

Answer (score -1):

I've had some serious, time consuming issues trying to uninstall "Java 7 Update 7", but finally found something that worked (Windows 7, 64-bit)

It's a program called "Revo Uninstaller Pro" (http://www.revouninstaller.com/). There's an option for a 30-day trial download.

In the program UI, type java in search, it finds Java 7 Update 7, highlight it, choose uninstall, after this select Scan (I chose Moderate, explained in UI), it finds lots of strings in the registry, bits and pieces, I selected each folder/content by hand (though it's possible to Select All) - and finally chose **Delete**.

After this, and a restart, the newest Java installed with no problems, and everything works now.